# Anime where man is crossing the street. Saved from an accident by someone who knew him in a past life (as a girl)

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw a trailer for an anime that caught my eye and so saved it. I think the trailer was deleted as I can't find the video anymore and it didn't look like it was uploaded by the company who made it. So this is where I tell you all I remember I'm bad at names which is obvious.

So a student I believe is crossing the street when a truck with no driver almost hits him when a man saves him. The man knows his name and says that some people are more accessible for the darkness ( I think ) to harm. It become redundantly clear the man who saved him knew him in a past life as a girl and I believe the man will protect him .

I have a shoddy memory but would be elated if someone found the anime. I believe the man who was saved was called haru or that could be the different animes I've been watching swirling together.

Comment: [Tokyo Ravens](https://www.baka-tsuki.org/project/index.php?title=Tokyo_Ravens:Volume12_Chapter4)?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: [Rave Master](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9WlUc8N7z0)?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's either of them though I will be watching Tokyo Raven XD

Comment: *"Found it 'the betrayal knows my name' I think :)"* Don't edit questions to add the answer! Either delete the question or enter it as an answer below.

Comment: What Andrew said - when you confirm that it is the anime you've been looking for, please post it as an answer, or at least leave a comment to confirm

Comment: Sorry didn't know :)

Answer (score 11):

'[The Betrayal Knows My Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Betrayal_Knows_My_Name)' is the anime I was looking for.

> Sakurai Yuki is a teenager with a mysterious power. He was abandoned
>   at birth near the Asahi orphanage. Because of that event, Yuki strives
>   for independence. He hates being a burden to anyone near him, but at
>   the same time, he is afraid of being left alone. Moreover, ever since
>   he can remember, he has had a strange ability that when he touches
>   others, he can feel their emotion. Unable to control it, he's often
>   made insensitive blunders in the past. He later meets a mysterious yet
>   beautiful stranger who saves his life, but for some reason he feels
>   like he's met before. While death looms and his ability gets stronger
>   and stronger, a man who claims to be his older brother suddenly
>   appears. What will Yuki do when he learns the truth?

Comment: @Valorum I didn't even know I could be ninja'd while reviewing VLQ

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Gotta be quicker than a ninja

Comment: 48 hours after the question is posted, you can accept a self answer. Please do so. :)